# Jaguar v6 petrol 3.0 2010 STFT and timing all over the place

Tags: fuel-trims, jaguar

2010 XF petrol 3.0 P171 and P174 and timing issue

For the last few months I’ve had both codes, so the time has come to resolve it, so far no joy, what have I done so far, the car also has a poor idle and has got worse from year one. No other error codes. Jaguar looked at the car 3 times over the years to find the poor idea and failed. It’s now at the point it needs fixing.

changed the maf
checked for vacuum leak, used smoke and pressure No leaks detacted
striped the manifold off and replaces the O rings around the pvc vacuum pipes
all cleaned and reassembled
cleared faults, disconnected he battery, after five mins both codes back

the car runs on LPG and petrol, I get the fault on both fuels, it runs 5% petrol while on gas.

Smoke tested again, nothing,

ok, main fold off again and bit the bullet and removed the Lower manifold as well, it’s very messy, but the seals are good.

All ideas welcome, still in a thousand pieces, so anything else to check.

Thankyou for looking

Geoff 
Here’s a odd video of the problem 
https://youtu.be/gVzRX0gxw0M

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I would check that the valves for the variable induction system are working properly.  Perhaps one is stuck open?